# print a range of numbers with different colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How should you print a range of numbers with different colors in an HTML page? E.g.: 1-10 red, 11-20 blue. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            for(i=0;i<=100;i++) {
               document.write(i);
               if(i>30 && i<50) {
                   document.write(i,'<FONT COLOR="red">');
               }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The tutorial you're following is extremely outdated and very bad.

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) only accepts one string parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your output from this function would not enclose the (i) element in the  block.  Amending your code to enclose the i within the html tags should do the trick!

```
<HTML>
<body>
<script>
for(i=0;i<=100;i++) {
    if(i>30 && i<50) {
       document.write('<FONT COLOR="red">' + i + '</font>');
    } else {
       document.write('<Font Color="black">' + i + '</font>');
    }
}

<script>
<body>
<HTML>
```

You could use case statements, or even iterate through an array of colors.  My preferred method is using jquery selectors and css classes though. 
Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erichyde/e0dk676L/) of this method.

Comment: Missing a quote before the second `</font>`. It ended up after `<HTML>`. Also, those last tags should be `</script>`, `</body>`, and `</html>`.

Comment: what should i write in front of case?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp is a link to the javascript Switch statement.  Basically depending on the number (or range of numbers) you input, it will do a different document.write.

Comment: thanks.could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?for(i=0;i<=100;i++) {
 switch(document.writeln(i)) {
  case i<=10:
   document.writeln('<FONT COLOR="red">' + i + '</font>');
  }
 }

Comment: Your switch needs to be on just i, so switch(i) rather than the document.writein(i).  Please mark mine as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's better to use javascript's [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) (Document Object Model) with [styles](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) or [classes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp), the js will look something like:

```
var numbers = document.createElement('div');

for(i=0;i<=100;i++) {    
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.textContent = i;
   numbers.appendChild(span);
   if(i>30 && i<50) {
       span.style.color = 'red';
   }
}

document.body.appendChild(numbers);
```

Comment: Did you check the output?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `document.write` line to something like this:

```
document.write("<span style='color: red'>" + String(i) + "</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>`. Try this:

```
    function color(thecolor, val) {
        return '<span style="color:' + thecolor + '"' + '>' + val + '</span>';
    }
    function func() {
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            if(i>30 && i<50)
            {
            document.write(color('green',i));
            }
           else
            {
               document.write(color('red',i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the output [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/4h3jjn)